# R shiny: optional parameters in function within renderUI do not work

Tags: r, function, shiny

Within my app, I'm using renderUI to display filters only after a data frame has been selected. I've written my own function to distribute the selectInput elements to a number of columns given by a function parameter.

I add the possibility of specifying `rosterWidth`, the number of columns that should be displayed per row, and `columnWidth`, the argument passed to `shiny::column` as the width parameter.

Ideally, I'd want to only have to specify one of these parameters, and my function should calculate the other based on `otherParam = 12 %/% firstParam` (since 12 is the maximum width allowed in shiny).

My function:

```
arrangeHtmlItems <- function(rosterWidth, columnWidth, htmlItemList, actionButton) {
  if (missing(rosterWidth) && missing(columnWidth)) {
    stop("Specify either rosterWidth or columnWidth")
    return(NULL)
  }

  if (missing(rosterWidth)) {
    rosterWidth <- 12 %/% columnWidth
  }

  if (missing(columnWidth)) {
    columnWidth <- 12 %/% rosterWidth
  }

  # number of columns needed
  numCols <- min(length(htmlItemList), rosterWidth)

  # item indices to use in for-loop
  itemIndices <- 1:length(htmlItemList)

  # column indices: column 1 should be first, column 0 should be the last column,
  # since i %% numCols for i == numCols is 0
  # (in a four-column roster, the first item is attributed to column 0 since 4 %% 4 is 0)
  columnIndices <- c(1:(numCols - 1), 0)

  cols <- list()
  for (i in 1:length(columnIndices)) {
    curIndex <- columnIndices[i]
    curCol <- htmlItemList[which(itemIndices %% numCols == curIndex)]
    cols[[i]] <- column(columnWidth, curCol)
  }

  # return action button in fluid row if given as parameter
  if(missing(actionButton)) {
    return(fluidRow(cols))
  } else {
    return(fluidRow(cols, actionButton))
  }
}
```

My app:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)

source("functions.R")

server <- function(input, output) {
  CtryData <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
    data <- data.frame(mpg)
  })

  output$colFilter <- renderUI({
    # make objects out of reactive objects
    data <- CtryData()
    cols <- colnames(data)

    # function returns fluidRows with number of columns specified by rosterWidth
    # dynamically adjusts the number of items per column based on number of filters produced in the lapply-function
    arrangeHtmlItems(
      # !!! 
      # rosterWidth * columnWidth must be <= 12
      # !!!
      rosterWidth = 2
      , columnWidth = 6
      , htmlItemList = lapply(cols, function(i) {
        vec_choices <- c("(All)", paste0(sort(unique(data[ ,i])))) # paste0 is needed since otherwise level numbers, not levels are listed for factors 
        selectInput(
          inputId = paste0("colFilter_", i),
          paste0("Select ", i),
          choices = vec_choices,
          multiple = TRUE,
          selectize = FALSE,
          size = 6,
          selected = "(All)"
        )
      })
      , actionButton("colFilterButton", "Go")
    )
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    actionButton("goButton", "Go")
    , uiOutput("colFilter")
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This works fine and the way I expect it to. 
However, when I write leave out `columnWidth` within the `arrangeHtmlItems()` function, the app throws a warning saying `column width must be between 1 and 12` instead of going into my bit of code where `columnWidth <- 12 %/% rosterWidth`. 
The same happens when I define the function as

```
arrangeHtmlItems <- function(rosterWidth = NULL, columnWidth = NULL, htmlItemList, actionButton) {
  ...
  if (is.null(columnWidth)) {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Why is this? How can I properly use optional function parameters in a function within `renderUI()`?

Comment: Your code is right... except that the last argument for actionButton is not named. You need to do `arrangeHtmlItems(rosterWidth=..,htmlItemList=..,actionButton=..)`, otherwise the actionButton will be passed in as the columnWidth. I found this out by setting breakpoints in the function, you can do that too.

Comment: you're right! Thank you very much! I'll use breakpoints from now on.